# What to do? I have one interview for a great company, another one called me today!

Tags: job-offer

I have applied to a number of positions and have received a Skype interview request from one company which I very much prefer. This interview would be scheduled sometime over the next three days.

However, today I received an interview request and test package for a different, ***part-time***, position for which I will receive my answer far sooner than the first company. This position has the potential to develop into a full-time job in the future.

I have so far not returned my test materials to them because I am uncertain whether I want to give up my chance at the full-time position. My questions are:

**Am I sinking my chances with the first company by proceeding with the interview process for the part-time position?**

Comment: What country and jurisdiction? If in the US, you have a lot of flexibility to quit and go to another company even after starting work. As far as I know, you generally are no more obligated by interviewing than the company is.

Comment: You can interview for both, but even if you *had* to choose one, your preference is offering you full-time work and another company is offering you part-time work that *might* become full-time. Logically, no competition.

Answer (score 12):

Calm down. Of course you still attend the second interview. I have given this advice on Workplace SE almost daily since joining:

> **Always keep your own goals and interests in mind**

Companies certainly will, and they won't care if achieving ***their*** goals hurts you in any way.

You have zero guarantees that this second interview will work out, so proceed to interview for the part-time airport position.

If a later date this second company offers you a position then you can quit the part-time position as politely as possible, and move on to the company that's offering you better opportunities.

You would only be hired as part-time anyway, those sort of positions typically have pretty high turn-over rates.

Answer (score 0):

Companies perform well when they find good employees and treat them well. You can use your situation to help you get the best terms. For some companies and/or jobs, that bar is low and treatment/terms are not very good. Even so, when you have more than one option, if you communicate well and perform well, it should help you get the job that is best suited for you.

Here are some pointers that will help you handle the situation - assuming your goal is to maximize both your compensation and your job stability (but it does not reduce your anxiety as fast as possible):

1. Schedule the interview with the full-time job for as soon as you feel comfortable doing it. Later today even, if that is possible. Time is short - make the most of it!
2. The company with the part-time job may have a hard time keeping people. That means you may not like it. You should learn as much as you can about why they are going so fast.
3. If offered the part-time job, it should be acceptable respond, "I have another opportunity I'm considering. I would like a few days to think about your offer to be sure I'm making a good decision." If they say "no, decide now" - then you can take the job, *but you warned them of your other option.* It is also acceptable to ask if/when it will become a full-time job and employment terms. (Although unless the response is a promise in writing, it may not ever happen...)
4. If you can, before you interview with the full-time job company tell them that you are interviewing for another job (or have another offer). Ask them **when you can expect a response** so you can plan and communicate appropriately. This shows concern for good communication and that you are valuable to someone else. They should take the matter seriously. This is a request not a demand or an attempt to pressure them because they may simply respond, "we can't move fast, so don't expect any response from us. Thank you, good-bye."
5. If not before your interview, at the end of your interview for the full-time job tell them about the other interview/job, just as described above. Also remember that you may get a response like, "it will take us 6 weeks to decide." Maybe you can fill that time with the part-time job? Regardless, it will give you critical information to help you make good life decisions.

Unless you sign something that legally binds you either job (which is rare in the US), then you should not have a problem with these options. You may even be able to accept one of the job, then use that for a better offer (pay, benefits, etc.) from the other one while still being a professional about it. Even taking the full-time job offer after rejecting the part-time job could lead to them making a better full-time job offer (unlikely, but not impossible).